# Filter out duplicate phone numbers from an Airtable column

Tags: airtable

I copied phone number data into [Airtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airtable).  There are duplicate entries, specifically for a "phone number" type column.

How do I filter out duplicates?

Or even mark a column as unique so that a phone number, in this case, is only ever entered once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airtable does not support this currently.

This is the workaround for finding duplicate entries in a field:

- Copy/paste the field into any field other than the primary field.
- Reconfigure that field as a [linked record field](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/206452848-Linked-record-fields) that links to a new table.
- On the new table, any duplicate entries should consolidate to individual records. Create a [count field](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/202576519-Guide-to-formula-lookup-count-and-rollup-fields) that on the new table.
- On the original table, create a lookup field that pulls in the count field from the new table.
- You can then [group](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/221747587-Guide-to-grouped-records) the original table by this lookup field and all of the duplicate records should come to the top.

I've went ahead and contacted Zach from Airtable, and got this reponse:

> Airtable doesn't currently have a way to disallow duplicate entries,
>   but I know this is something on our team's radar. I'm happy to pass
>   along this feedback to our team and keep you posted when we have news
>   to share.